# Which spark should I download?

Tags: apache-spark

I'm new to spark and try to build spark+hadoop+hive environment.
I've download the lastest version hive, and accroding to the [Version Compatibility] section on the  https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Hive+on+Spark%3A+Getting+Started, I should download spark 2.3.0, and at the page https://archive.apache.org/dist/spark/spark-2.3.0/, I found there are some different versions, such as spark-2.3.0-bin-hadoop2.7.tgz, spark-2.3.0-bin-without-hadoop.tgz, SparkR_2.3.0.tar.gz and so on.
Now I'm confused! I don't konw which version of spark I need download, and if I download spark-2.3.0-bin-hadoop2.7.tgz, is it mean I need't download hadoop? And what's the different between SparkR_2.3.0.tar.gz and spark-2.3.0-bin-without-hadoop.tgz?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should download the latest version that includes Hadoop since that's what you want to setup. That would be Spark 3.x, not 2.3

If you already have Hadoop environment (HDFS/YARN), download the one without Hadoop.

If you're not going to right R code, don't download the SparkR version

AFAIK, "Spark on Hive" execution engine is no longer being worked on. Spark Thriftserver can be used in place of running your own HiveServer

Comment: you mean I need't install hive anymore, just use Spark Thriftserver ?

Comment: You can use Hive, too. Or you can only use the Hive Metastore with SparkSQL + ThriftServer. My point was that the feature-set for the wiki link you sent is not part of Spark, and I thought I read somewhere that the Hive developers weren't supporting it, or planning on updating it for Spark 3